# Is it possible to change a switch variable within a case?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to run some code to change the switch variable to jump to whatever case i want it to. I have a feeling I'm approaching it wrong.

```cs
int option = 0;

while(true) {

  switch(option) {

    case 0:
       ConsoleKeyInfo TurnChoice = Console.ReadKey();

       switch(TurnChoice.key) 
       {

       case ConsoleKey.M
         option = 2;
         break;

       case ConsoleKey.S
         option = 1;
         break;
       }
       break;

    case 1:
       /* run some code */
       break;

    case 2: 
       /* run some code */
    ...
```

I expected it to jump to `case: 2` when the `M` key is pressed but instead it just keeps looping `case: 0`.

Comment: I would suggest a recursive method call where `option` is your method parameter

Comment: I tried your [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t0ZgG6) and it runs like expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just on the code you have shown, this looks more than a little suspect

Why not `switch` on your input and be done with it

```
while(true) 
{

  switch(Console.ReadKey()) 
  {
     case ConsoleKey.M :
       // do M stuff
       break;
     ...
```

If you need a state-machine, or a more complex hierarchy, i suggest breaking this up into more logical units, and not try and do everything in the one loop

Answer (score 0):

I suggest turning `switch` into `if / else` where you can modify `option` quite legally:

```
   while (true) {
     if (0 == option) {
       ConsoleKeyInfo TurnChoice = Console.ReadKey();

       if (TurnChoice.key == ConsoleKey.M) 
         option = 2;
       else if (TurnChoice.key == case ConsoleKey.S)
         option = 1;
     } 

     if (1 == option) {
       ...
     }
     else if (2 == option) { // drop "else" if option can be changed within if (option == 1)
       ...
     } 
   }
```

Another (less readable) possibility is to put `continue` instead of `break`:

```
while(true) {

  switch(option) {

    case 0:
       ConsoleKeyInfo TurnChoice = Console.ReadKey();

       switch(TurnChoice.key) 
       {

       case ConsoleKey.M
         option = 2;
         continue;        // <- continue instead of break

       case ConsoleKey.S
         option = 1;
         continue;        // <- continue instead of break
       }
       ...
```

in this case we change `option` come back to `while` and re-enter into `switch`